# Is there a data base, tool or method I can use to find out which of my genes code for cytokine receptors?

Tags: molecular-biology, gene-expression, rna-sequencing, receptor, ontology

I have a list of over 600 differentially expressed genes from my single cell RNA seq data analyses. I want to proceed to find out which of my genes code for cytokine receptors so that I can show on a heat map how their expression varies across clusters. Can any one give me a hint on which tool or method I can use to find out which of my genes code for cytokine receptors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're saying you want to convert the gene IDs to gene symbols such as IL15RA? R script typically works

Comment: As pointed out by @CKM, this is a simple case of finding the gene name corresponding to the ids used in the sequencing analysis. It's quite straightforward if you have a table of gene ids and corresponding names. You can do it manually for a small set of genes or use a simple script in your favorite programming language for parsing the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways to go about this (including literature research via PubMed), but for a start, I searched the [GO term data base](http://www.informatics.jax.org/vocab/gene_ontology/) which, for the search term "cytokine receptor activity" returned [this](http://www.informatics.jax.org/vocab/gene_ontology/GO:0004896), which includes a number of genes which I can download as an excel file and match them with my gene set using R.

Comment: You stole this answer from someone who answered you on Biostars.  https://www.biostars.org/p/365294/  Are you going to give yourself the best answer points now?

Comment: @swbarnes2: I asked the question on both fora and I want to share what I learned from another forum on this forum. This is because the answers I got on this forum did not directly meet my needs but I do appreciate the responses I got here. Is it a crime? By the way I slightly modified the response suggested to suit my needs.